# spring не приходит результат form:checkboxes

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

Сделал класс User и UserRole, хочу при регистрации пользователя, чтобы все роли выдавались списком, а потом выбрать необходимые. Проблема в том, что список ролей выводится, а в контроллер не возвращаются выбранные роли.

User

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Size(min = 3, max = 50)
    @Column(name = "LOGIN", nullable = false)
    private String login;

    @Size(min = 8, max = 256)
    @Column(name = "PASSWORD", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "USER2ROLE", joinColumns =
    { @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns =
    { @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID") })
    private Set<UserRole> rols = new HashSet<UserRole>(0);

    public User()
    {
    }

    public String getLogin()
    {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login)
    {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword()
    {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password)
    {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Set<UserRole> getRols()
    {
        return rols;
    }

    public void setRole(Set<UserRole> rols)
    {
        this.rols = rols;
    }

    public Long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
}
```

UserRole

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERROLE")
public class UserRole implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ROLE_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Size(min = 3, max = 50)
    @Column(name = "ROLE", nullable = false)
    private String role;

    public UserRole()
    {
    }

    public Long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getRole()
    {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role)
    {
        this.role = role;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof UserRole))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return this.getId().compareTo(((UserRole) obj).getId()) == 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        if (getId() != null)
            return getId().hashCode();
        return super.hashCode();
    }
}
```

Контроллер

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/adduser", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addUser(Model model)
    {
        User user = new User();
        List<UserRole> allRole = userService.getAllRole();
        Set<UserRole> allSetRole=new HashSet<UserRole>();
        for (UserRole userRole : allRole)
            allSetRole.add(userRole);
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        model.addAttribute("allRole", allSetRole);
        return "users/adduser";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/adduser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveUser(User user, Model model)
    {
        String message = "Успех! Пользователь добавлен.";
        if (!user.getRols().isEmpty())
            userService.saveUser(user);
        else
            message = "Печаль";
        model.addAttribute("title", "Добавление пользователя");
        model.addAttribute("msg", message);
        model.addAttribute("linkto", "/");
        return "success";
    }
```

Ну и сама jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>




<div class="container">
        <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="user">
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="login">Логин: </label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="login" id="login" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><label for="password">Пароль: </label></td>
                    <td><form:password path="password" id="password" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><form:checkboxes items="${allRole}"
                            itemLabel="role" itemValue="id" path="rols" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" value="Зарегистрировать" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form:form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В user в сеттере

```
public void setRole(Set<UserRole> rols)
{
    this.rols = rols;
}
```

Опечатка, потому он и не срабатывал, надо setRols

Answer (score 0):

Возможно проблема в том, что надо настроить каскадирование, то есть когда в базе сохраняется пользователь, сохраняются и привязанный к нему список ролей

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "USER2ROLE", joinColumns =
{ @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns =
{ @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID") })
private Set<UserRole> rols = new HashSet<UserRole>(0);
```

Таким образом, все операции с пользователем (добавление, обновление, удаление) будут распространяться и на его роли. Надеюсь Вам это поможет.

Comment: Чтобы в базу залить, надо собрать user`а и сохранить его, а у меня с формы не приходят отмеченные роли. Каскадирование тут не поможет